# How do I pass multiple queried results to new a query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have succeeded in querying one table to get information that is needed to query another table (If you can see a better way I would be grateful!)

**My question is:** How can I have multiple values come back from the first query and have my second query come back with multiple results.
As you can see I am inserting the returned result from query one into query two “msg_id = ?”(I use '$datas' to fill the ‘?’) but if my results from query one have multiple values then how will this work?

**Also** how can I make it get multiple results from query one? at the moment if there are multiple values in mysql it only grabs the first one it reads.

My **MODEL** code is as follows:

```
function check() {
    $this->db->select('msgto_message');
    $this->db->from('msgto');
    $this->db->where('msgto_display', 'y');
    $this->db->where('msgto_recipient', '1'); 

    $w = $this->db->get();

    if ($w->num_rows() > 0) {
           $rowe = $w->row_array(); 

           $datas = $rowe['msgto_message'];
    }

    $sql = "SELECT msg_content FROM msg WHERE msg_id = ?"; 

$data = $this->db->query($sql, $datas) or die(mysql_error());

if ($data->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach($data->result_array() as $row) {
        $data = $row;
        }

        return $data;
    }

}
```

My **CONTROLLER** code is as follows:

```
function index() {
    $this->load->model('data_model');
    $data['rows'] = $this->data_model->check();

    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

**Thank you anyone that helps me, I greatly appreciate it!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find a database join helpful here. While I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here (especially in that foreach loop!), something like this might get you going in a more efficient direction:

```
function check() {
    $this->db->select('msg.msg_content');
    $this->db->from('msgto');
    $this->db->join('msg', 'msgto.msgto_message = msg.msg_id');
    $this->db->where('msgto.msgto_display', 'y');
    $this->db->where('msgto.msgto_recipient', '1'); 

    $data = $this->db->get();

    if ($data->num_rows() > 0) {
      return $data->result_array();
    }
}
```

This asks the database to join together the `msg` and `msgto` tables based on `msgto_message` matching `msg_id`, and can use the WHERE critera on `msgto` while returning the results from `msg`.

Comment: Thank you very much! this is exactly what I have been trying to do for the last two days! Thanks again! I cant state that enough!

Answer (score 0):

Right not you are getting only the first row from query one 

`if ($w->num_rows() > 0) {
           $rowe = $w->row_array();`

```
       $datas = $rowe['msgto_message'];
}
```

To get all the records you need to cycle through the result


`if ($w->num_rows() > 0) {

   foreach($rowe = $w->row_array() as $datas) {`

```
  $datas = $rowe['msgto_message'];

  $sql = "SELECT msg_content FROM msg WHERE msg_id = ?"; 

  $data = $this->db->query($sql, $datas) or die(mysql_error());

  if ($data->num_rows() > 0) {
       foreach($data->result_array() as $row) {
          $data = $row;
       }

       return $data;
  }
```

}

}

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! Am I correct in saying that "foreach($rowe = $w->row_array()) {" should be "foreach($rowe = $w->row_array() as $datas) {" ?